# Looking for resources to learn SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm very new to SQL Server. I got a task from my boss where it involves SQL Server. He gave me a little introduction about it but I would like to know if there are other ways on how to deal with it.

I have a little background on Access but not that so intensive.

I would like to ask your opinion, where to start if you're dealing with SQL Server data bank.

Would appreciate your ideas.

Comment: One piece of information: the product is named "SQL Server".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) is a good place to start

Comment: This really is one of the *best* places to start.  Once you get that, try picking up a copy of "SQL Pocket Guide" from O'Reilly publishing.  Great to have by your side because it compares all of the various SQL/DB-flavors.

Comment: @j0rd4n: thanks:-) I checked the link and it looks very interesting I'll start learning now:-)

Comment: i don't think one should use w3schools. it's pooly written and full of errors (for more information, take a look at http://w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.sqlcourse.com/ pretty much explains all the basics for using SQL as a language. It will help you to understand the basic statements and how to create queries. I would then use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167593.aspx to learn how to use the SQL server management studio and get familiar with the Microsoft way of doing SQL.

Comment: @Molex: yes I also started the www.sqlcourse.com.This is also a very good site.

Answer (score 2):

just for your information:
microsoft based products are generally not plain sql but they have some additional commands you might use. this means that SQL written for a microsoft sql server might not entirely run on a mysql- or postgre-server.

therefore you need to know what your sql-knowledge needs to be applied to.

in my opinion, [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/default.asp) is a good start where you can find tutos including examples etc.

regards

Comment: @Atmocreations, just to clarify it goes both ways every DBMS has it's own unique functions and SQL conventions.

Comment: yes sure. i meant this as an example... maybe i didn't point out that one well enough ;o)

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with Access, you might take a little time to review some queries you created that you know well in Access's SQL-mode.  It's not perfect SQL, but it might help you understand some of the things you've already done in a different frame.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for books on the subject, I really enjoyed and learned a great deal from the two books by Michael Hernandez, [SQL Queries for Mere Mortals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321444434) and [Database Design for Mere Mortals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201752840). Both highly recommended!

Marc

Comment: @marc_s: I've heard that this is really a good book. Thanks for recommending:-)

Answer (score 1):

This resource isn't specifically for SQL Server, but it is a good vendor neutral intro to generic SQL and everything in here will apply to SQL Server:

http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsql/

Like the w3c schools page, here is the corresponding try queries yourself page:

http://headfirstlabs.com/sql_hands_on/

Answer (score 1):

Any idea if your company has access to any online reference book libraries?

My last two have been members of at least one site where you can log in and get access to probably thousands of coding/database books.  I've found it really helpful in the past and it might be worth asking.

Comment: @PassingStranger:yes my boss has access on msdn. I think he also have an account there.